# how beeline uses jceks file

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I am hiding the metastore password in hive-site.xml using below property and I am using postgres as my metastore db.

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.credential.provider.path</name>
    <value>jceks://file//...hive_new.jceks</value>
  </property>
```

1)Iam getting error when I initiate db like "schematool -dbType postgres -initSchema"?

2)How can I use the these jceks file using beeline?.I have tried like below

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://myhost:1000/default;principal=hive/principal@REALM?hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs@hostname/path/to/jceks"
```

but its halted at connecting.....

Do I need to set any other properties in hive-site.xml for beeline?

Comment: Beeline is not supposed to connect to the Metastore DB. It connects to HiveServer2; which connects to the Metastore service;  which connects to the DB. And nowadays there's an easier way to "hide the password": store all private Metastore properties in `hivemetastore-site.xml` and protect the file so that only the service account running Metastore can read it.

Comment: Caveat: `schematool` only uses `hive-site.xml` so you have to build a full conf, incl. password in clear text, to initialize the DB. Then you have to edit the conf to (a) try the JCEKS and probably fail, or (b) use the dedicated Metastore conf.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Can u confirm that "hadoop.security.credential.provider.path" property should include in hive-site.xml ?.I saw some sites this property is included in hadoop core-site.xml. Do you have any steps to implement metastore password encryption in hive services.I am using postgres as metasore